# Moving a SharePoint 2010 folder (with documents in it) from one document library to another

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have a document library with a lot of folders into it and i need to move them to another document library given that a site column had a certain value. The destination list was created from a template of the original list. I have created a workflow to do this but I seem to get an error every time.

Workflow:
[image: this is the workflow]

The error i get is this: 
[image]

Everything works fine if i am trying to move just a document but as soon as I try to move a folder the workflow breaks.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: can you please check the Logs and post the error message.

Comment: Are you referring to the workflow history i.e. http://yoursitename/WorkflowHistory/AllItems.aspx? If so then that list isn't showing me all that much.. Just repeats the same error message and shows me some GUIDs. I don't know where I would find the logs in the server..

Comment: @AkarshGupta any advice you can give me? Thanks!

Comment: Go to Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS and run the workflow and check for latest updated log file. There you will find the error and it's detailed description.